# How to change the background color of a parent component from a child component

Tags: lit-element, dispatchevent

I am studying the LitElement technology and I have an exercise which I cannot solve completely, I have to nest two components, where the child component will have 3 buttons and depending on the button that is pressed, the background of the component must be changed father, I understand that for this exercise you must use customizable events with DispatchEvent, I leave you my code that I have been doing for this exercise and I also share some screens of how this exercise should work, I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance

[image pressing the green button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqQzh.png)

[image pressing the red button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q81TS.png)

[image pressing the blue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k194h.png)

[child component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMc5F.png)

[Parent component image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuXsg.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I need to do is have two nested components, in the child component there are going to be some buttons and depending on the button that is pressed, the background of the parent component must change the color selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is hard to understand the problem without including the code.

```
static styles = css`
  :host{
   ..your style   
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

post a photo of the code, they are as a link, there is an image to represent what I want to do and there are the images of all the code of the parent and child components

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In you child component to push and event outside shadow dom, your event should have composed set to true
e.g.

```js
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('myEventName',{bubbles:true,
composed:true,
detail: my-details})
```

And at parent you need to consume the event with `@`
e.g.

```html
<my-child @myEventName=${this.handleMyEvent($event)}></my-child>
```

useful links

- https://lit.dev/docs/components/events/#shadowdom-composed
- https://lit.dev/docs/components/events/#dispatching-events-after-an-element-updates

Comment: ok thank you very much for the help, I will try as you tell me